# i can't understand this code (assembly)

Tags: assembly

What does this code do? I don't understand what it does.

```
MOV AH,00H
MOV AL,BL
MOV LP,CL
MOV CL,10
DIV CL
MOV CL,LP
```

Comment: Do you understand how the `DIV` instruction works? What registers it operates on?

Comment: yes it means division that we division cl on cl

Comment: Have you tried a simple google search to learn about Assembly commands? You should try and rephrase your question to ask about a specific problem you're having rather than asking "what does this code do?"

Comment: No, it does *not* divide CL by CL. It divides something else by CL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Store the value 0 in register AH.
2. Store the value in register BL in register AL.
3. Store the contents of register CL in register LP
4. Store the value 10 in register CL
5. Divide contents of CL by contents of AX
6. Store the Value LP in CL.

In summary, this code divides the number "10" by whatever was stored in register BL.  The answer is located in register AL.  Remainder is located in AH.

Line 2 backs up the CL register (since it gets overwritten).  Line 5 restores it.

Comment: It divides the other way around, though (AX by 10)

Comment: You really should rework this answer. It has many flaws!